# Facing NoSuchMethodError and NoClassDefFoundError after Spring boot upgrade from 2.4.x to 2.5.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, build.gradle

Error logged while running **gradle clean build**:

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException> but was<java.lang.NoSuchMethodError>
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:30)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlin.collections.MapsKt.createMapBuilder()Ljava/util/Map;
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.Visibilities.(Visibilities.kt:56)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.Visibility.compareTo(Visibility.kt:23)
at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.DescriptorVisibility.compareTo(DescriptorVisibility.kt:66)

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21' // Required for Kotlin integration  
    ext.spring_boot_version = '2.6.6'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // Required for Kotlin integration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#kotlin-spring-compiler-plugin
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'kotlin' // Required for Kotlin integration
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#kotlin-spring-compiler-plugin
apply plugin: "jacoco"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlin_version}" // Required for Kotlin integration
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlin_version}"
   // implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.7'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc"    
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.27.2'
    testImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.6'
    testImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.6'   
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    // end::tests[]
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention which classes and methods are you missing, by following packages you can check what was removed, and add dependencies for those removed classes which contain the missing methods.

Comment: Cucumber and junit test cases fails with com.xxx.yyyTests> givenAuthenticationEndpointReturnsSuccessfulResponse_ownerIdReturned FAILED
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at yyyTests.kt

Comment: com.xxx.yyyTests > givenAddTendersCalled_ApiCalledWithCorrectParameters FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Visibility.kt:23 - using jacoco 0.8.1 -    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.5"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.5"

Comment: @zawarudo please edit and add the stack traces and errors to your question

Comment: Errors like this come from incompatible versions of jars or external libraries. If you are using Spring Cloud next to Spring Boot those are strictly tied to versions (the same applies to other libraries). Without seeing the actual erorr stacktrace and your dependencies this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Hi @zawarudo, Please check above the error and gradle file settings and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the old version of Kotlin-stdlib, maybe `1.3`. Some dependency is causing your code to use this downgraded version. Please look at the external libraries, you will be able to find `1.6.21` and `1.3.11` version of `kotlin-stdlib`.

`MapKt.createMapBuilder` is present in `1.6` versions, not in `1.3`.

Run `./gradlew appname:dependencies` and see which dependencies are using this dependency.

There will be something like

`kotlin-stdlib-1.6.21--->1.3.21` (or `11` or some other version)

If that is the case, you need to see the dependency insight to see which dependency is using this prev version: that is `1.3`

You can run `cd ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`

search this version number:

`grep -r "1.3.11"`

In my case, the version of `kotlin-stdlib` is `1.3.11`.

You will be able to find out the dependency that is causing this downgrade to happen.